# Run a YAML SSM Run Document from AWS Lambda with Parameters

Tags: python, aws-lambda, yaml, boto3, aws-ssm

I am trying to run a `YAML SSM` document from a `Python AWS Lambda`, using `boto3 ssm.send_command` with parameters, but even if I'm just trying to run the sample "Hello World", I get:

> "errorMessage": "An error occurred (InvalidParameters) when calling the SendCommand operation: document TestMessage does not support parameters.

JSON Run Documents work without an issue, so it seems like the parameters are being passed in JSON format, but the document I intend this for contains a relatively long Powershell script, JSON needing to run it all on a single line would be awkward, and I am hoping to avoid needing to run it from an S3 bucket. Can anyone suggest a way to run a YAML Run Document with parameters from the Lambda?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know AWS lambda always gets it's events as JSON. My suggestion would be that in the lambda_handler.py file declare a new variable like this:

```
import json
import yaml

def handler_name(event, context): 
    yaml_event = yaml.dump(json.load(event))
    #rest of the code...
```

This way the event will be in YAML format and you can use that variable instead of the event, which is in JSON format.

Comment: Thank you, Havacs.

This is good to know, however, I think my problem is in passing YAML parameters to SSM Run Document from Lambda, as opposed to passing YAML parameters to Lambda. Please let me know if I misunderstood, or if there is some solution you can see, which I can utilize in Run Document code. I will try to figure out something based on what you have informed, as well, to convert JSON to YAML input in the Run Document..

Comment: If you could show me your lambda function, that would be a great help to understand what could be the issue, also to see what boto3 methods are you using.

Comment: Sure. this is just a really simple one, for testing purposes:

import json
import boto3
ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    response = ssm_client.send_command(
        InstanceIds=[
            event['otherInput']['InstanceIds']
        ],
        DocumentName='TestMessage',
        Parameters={
            "message": ['- HI!']
        }
    )

As i'm sure you can tell, it just send a parameter to a "Hello World!" Run Document, to be relayed as output. I'll paste that in the next coment.

Comment: Here is the Run Document. When it's the JSON version, it works fine.

---
schemaVersion: "2.2"
description: "Command Document Example YAML Template"
parameters:
  Message:
    type: "String"
    description: "Example"
    default: "Hello World"
mainSteps:
- action: "aws:runPowerShellScript"
  name: "example"
  inputs:
    runCommand:
    - "Write-Output {{Message}}"

Comment: In this case I am really uncertain whether you can send YAML with boto3, because the Run document is going to get the response of the boto3.send_command() method and its response will always be in JSON format. If I find anything else I let you know, but I think at the moment it is not possible. :(

Comment: Hello Havacs,

I did some further digging, and it actually turned out that the results i was getting were a combination of a missing parameter in the main Run Document, and i think an update to the Lambda for using the test Hello World document instead having been applied only after a lag, which i've seen happen in AWS a few times. Everything is working now. Sorry for my confusion and thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of running a YAML Run Command document using boto3 `ssm.send_command` in a Lambda running Python 3.8. Variables are passed to the Lambda using either environment variables or SSM Parameter Store. The script is retrieved from S3 and accepts a single parameter formatted as a JSON string which is passed to the bash script running on Linux (sorry I don't have one for PowerShell).

The SSM Document is deployed using CloudFormation but you could also create it through the console or CLI. Based on the error message you cited, perhaps verify the Document Type is set as "Command".

SSM Document (wrapped in CloudFormation template, refer to the `Content` property)

```yaml
  Neo4jLoadQueryDocument: 
    Type: AWS::SSM::Document
    Properties:
      DocumentType: "Command"
      DocumentFormat: "YAML"
      TargetType: "/AWS::EC2::Instance"
      Content:
        schemaVersion: "2.2"
        description: !Sub "Load Neo4j for ${AppName}"
        parameters:
          sourceType:
            type: "String"
            description: "S3"
            default: "S3"
          sourceInfo:
            type: "StringMap"
            description: !Sub "Downloads all files under the ${AppName} scripts prefix"
            default:
              path: !Sub 'https://{{resolve:ssm:/${AppName}/${Stage}/${AWS::Region}/DataBucketName}}.s3.amazonaws.com/config/scripts/'
          commandLine:
            type: "String"
            description: "These commands are invoked by a Lambda script which sets the correct parameters (Refer to documentation)."
            default: 'bash start_task.sh'
          workingDirectory:
            type: "String"
            description: "Working directory"
            default: "/home/ubuntu"
          executionTimeout:
            type: "String"
            description: "(Optional) The time in seconds for a command to complete before it is considered to have failed. Default is 3600 (1 hour). Maximum is 28800 (8 hours)."
            default: "86400"
        mainSteps:
          - action: "aws:downloadContent"
            name: "downloadContent"
            inputs:
              sourceType: "{{ sourceType }}"
              sourceInfo: "{{ sourceInfo }}"
              destinationPath: "{{ workingDirectory }}"
          - action: "aws:runShellScript"
            name: "runShellScript"
            inputs: 
              runCommand:
                - ""
                - "directory=$(pwd)"
                - "export PATH=$PATH:$directory"
                - " {{ commandLine }} " 
                - ""
              workingDirectory: "{{ workingDirectory }}"
              timeoutSeconds: "{{ executionTimeout }}"
```

Lambda function

```py
import os
import boto3

neo4j_load_query_document_name = os.environ["NEO4J_LOAD_QUERY_DOCUMENT_NAME"]
# neo4j_database_instance_id = os.environ["NEO4J_DATABASE_INSTANCE_ID"]
neo4j_database_instance_id_param = os.environ["NEO4J_DATABASE_INSTANCE_ID_SSM_PARAM"]
load_neo4j_activity = os.environ["LOAD_NEO4J_ACTIVITY"]
app_name = os.environ["APP_NAME"]

# Get SSM Document Neo4jLoadQuery
ssm = boto3.client('ssm')
response = ssm.get_document(Name=neo4j_load_query_document_name)
neo4j_load_query_document_content = json.loads(response["Content"])

# Get Instance ID
neo4j_database_instance_id = ssm.get_parameter(Name=neo4j_database_instance_id_param)["Parameter"]["Value"]

# Extract document parameters
neo4j_load_query_document_parameters = neo4j_load_query_document_content["parameters"]
command_line_default = neo4j_load_query_document_parameters["commandLine"]["default"]
source_info_default = neo4j_load_query_document_parameters["sourceInfo"]["default"]

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    params = {
        "params": {
            "app_name": app_name,
            "activity_arn": load_neo4j_activity,
        }
    }

    # Include params JSON as command line argument
    cmd = f"{command_line_default} \'{json.dumps(params)}\'"

    try:
        response = ssm.send_command(
            InstanceIds=[
                neo4j_database_instance_id,
            ],
            DocumentName=neo4j_load_query_document_name,
            Parameters={
                "commandLine":[cmd],
                "sourceInfo":[json.dumps(source_info_default)]
            },
            MaxConcurrency='1')

        if response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] != 200:
            logger.error(json.dumps(response, cls=DatetimeEncoder))
            raise Exception("Failed to send command")
        else:
            logger.info(f"Command `{cmd}` invoked on instance {neo4j_database_instance_id}")
    
    except Exception as err:
        logger.error(err)
        raise err

    return
```

Parameters in a JSON document are not necessarily in JSON themselves, they can easily be string or numeric values (more likely IMO). If you want to pass a parameter in JSON format (not the same as a JSON document), pay attention to quotes and escaping.

Comment: Thank you, abk!

This is a fair bit for me to absorb, but I'm trying it.

Comment: @Sergey no problem, it seemed close enough to your use case to be useful, hopefully it is.